# Calcular produção por hora usando HTML5 e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Boas,

Sou novo por aqui e também na linguagem de programação :)

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora de Produção por hora em PHP.
Fiz parte do código, consigo alimentar os *input* e fazer o calculo, mas o resultado não sai em formato de HORAS (00:00:00), não consegui converter o valor, quero que seja preenchido os ":" automaticamente.

Preciso somar o tempo entre dois horários.

Exemplo: Inicio: 07:00:00 - Fim: 12:00:00 - Total: 05:00:00.

Desde já agradeço.

Segue abaixo o meu código. Porém aqui não está saindo o resultado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
 <title>Controle de produção</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
       <form method="post" action="index.php">
           <class>Início</class> <class>Fim</class> <class>Horas Trab.</class><br/>
           <input type="datatime" placeholder="inicio 1" name="i1"/>
           <input type="datatime" placeholder="fim 1" name="f1"/><br/>
           <input type="datatime" placeholder="inicio 2" name="i2"/>
           <input type="datatime" placeholder="fim 2" name="f2"/><br/>
           <input type="submit" value="Calcular produção"/>
       </form>
        <?php
        $inicio1 = isset($_POST["i1"])?$_POST["i1"]:'00:00:00';
        $inicio2 = isset($_POST["i2"])?$_POST["i2"]:0;
        $fim1 = isset($_POST["f1"])?$_POST["f1"]:0;
        $fim2 = isset($_POST["f2"])?$_POST["f2"]:0;
        $rht1 = ($fim1 - $inicio1);
        $rht2 = ($fim2 - $inicio2);
        
        echo "$rht1 e $rht2";
        
     ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você precisar usar `date` da uma olhada na documentação... https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Comment: Como eu disse, estou aprendendo programação, e ainda não sei ler as documentação, :), Com esse que me mandou comecei a entender como funciona a leitura do mesmo, mas se tiver alguma dica, ficarei grato. Agradeço pela atenção e ajuda que me deu ;), e também obrigado a todos que me responderam.

Answer (score 2):

Opa, conforme o Lodi comentou, seria legal voce dar uma olhada na documentação do PHP.

Esse exemplo aqui esta usando a classe [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php)

```
$inicio1 = new DateTime('10:00:00');
$fim1 = new DateTime('12:30:30');

$diff = $inicio1->diff($fim1);

$diff_horas = $diff->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Tem bastante coisa que da para fazer com essa classe.

Espero que te ajude. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Não use `type="datetime"` que está obsoleto (o Chrome mesmo não
>   suporta mais). Use `type="datetime-local"`.

Use a classe `DateTime()` nos valores enviados e pegue a diferença com `diff()`. No caso abaixo eu peguei as horas e os minutos separadamente e depois formatei com `date()`.

```
<div>
   <form method="post" action="teste2.php">
      <class>Início</class> <class>Fim</class> <class>Horas Trab.</class><br/>
      <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="inicio 1" name="i1"/>
      <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="fim 1" name="f1"/><br/>
      <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="inicio 2" name="i2"/>
      <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="fim 2" name="f2"/><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Calcular produção"/>
   </form>
   <?php
   $inicio1 = isset($_POST["i1"]) ? new DateTime($_POST['i1']) : 0;
   $inicio2 = isset($_POST["i2"]) ? new DateTime($_POST['i2']) : 0;
   $fim1 =    isset($_POST["f1"]) ? new DateTime($_POST['f1']) : 0;
   $fim2 =    isset($_POST["f2"]) ? new DateTime($_POST['f2']) : 0;
   $dif1 = $fim1->diff($inicio1);
   $dif2 = $fim2->diff($inicio2);

   // formata em horas (formato 24h) : minutos (00 a 59) : 00
   $rht1 = date("H:i:00", strtotime("$dif1->h:$dif1->i"));
   $rht2 = date("H:i:00", strtotime("$dif2->h:$dif2->i"));

   echo "$rht1 e $rht2";

   ?>
</div>
```